# Sonarqube + Postgresql containers unable to determine database dialect

Tags: docker, sonarqube, containers, dialect

I defined 2 services to run Sonarqube in a docker swarm :

```
version: "3"

services:

sonar-a:
    image: library/sonarqube:6.7.5
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL="jdbc:postgresql://10.11.12.13:5432/sonar"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == some-node

  sonar-a-db:
    image: library/postgres:10.5
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
     - POSTGRES_DB=sonar
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == some-node
```

(I removed the volumes to ease the tests)

But I always get this error that tells me Sonar cant "determine database dialect" :

> ...
>
> 2018.09.28 15:22:42 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
>
> 2018.09.28 15:22:42 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>
> 2018.09.28 15:22:42 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
>
> 2018.09.28 15:22:42 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.join.ParentJoinPlugin]
>
> 2018.09.28 15:22:42 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]
>
> 2018.09.28 15:22:42 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
>
> 2018.09.28 15:22:43 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
>
> 2018.09.28 15:22:43 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 7.1.0.11001 / 9f47ce9daecebb16fc777249a418252625ae774a
>
> 2018.09.28 15:22:43 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed: Unable to determine database dialect to use within sonar with
>   dialect null jdbc url "jdbc:postgresql://10.4.140.56:5432/sonar"
>
> 2018.09.28 15:22:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped 
>   ...

I tried different versions, I tried with mysql, I tried to pass a dialect variable in the SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL but nothing changes
Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in YAML should be defined without quotes. Right now your JDBC URL is equal to `"jdbc:postgresql://10.11.12.13:5432/sonar"` instead of the `jdbc:postgresql://10.11.12.13:5432/sonar`.

You have to change this:

```
- SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL="jdbc:postgresql://10.11.12.13:5432/sonar"
```

to:

```
- SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://10.11.12.13:5432/sonar
```

Comment: I had to wait till now to test it, and it works fine. Thank you for your explanation !